# mySQL UPDATE query local filepath

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a local file path which i would like to store in my table

```
$sqlsubject = "UPDATE documents SET subject = 'Art' WHERE documentname = '".addslashes($path)."\\\\".addslashes($file)."'";
```

Unfortunately this does not update the selected rows, if i echo the variable $sqlsubject i get:

```
UPDATE documents SET subject = 'Art' WHERE documentname = 'c:\\temp\\sourcedocuments\\lower\\Art\\testdocument.pdf'
```

If i copy this query and manually run it with mysql it updates correctly, if i add a static value it also adds correctly.
I feel like it has something to do with the backslashes?
Thanks

Comment: try this https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp

Comment: Have you tried prepared statement?

Comment: i think u have to put just two slashes not 4 `$sqlsubject = "UPDATE documents SET subject = 'Art' WHERE documentname = '".addslashes($path)."\\".addslashes($file)."'";`

Comment: Why do you use `addslashes`, but only for a part of the value? There are much better quoting strategies, and they should be applied to the **whole** value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use prepared statement for that:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE documents SET subject = "Art" WHERE documentname = :path';
$db->prepare($sql)->execute([':path' => $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file]);
```

Comment: I get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string when trying the above....

Comment: @Retroisbest `$db` should be instance of `PDO`, not string.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding several path  you could use  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

```
$my_full_path= $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
```